# What will happen if we skip reducer by keeping mapper and combiner in Mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

My input file that is of size 10 GB  is at

```
/user/cloudera/inputfiles/records.txt
```

Here is my Driver class code :

```
public class WordCountMain {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Path inputFilePath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputFilePath = new Path(args[1]);




Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");
job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.job.queue.name","omega");

    job.setJarByClass(WordCountMain.class);



    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(WordCountCombiner.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}
```

}

I have code for Mapper and Combiner ,I have set reducer to zero

Here is my Mapper code :

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,IntWritable>
{
public static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.InterruptedException
    {

    String line =   value.toString();
    String eachWord =null;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"|");

    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        eachWord = st.nextToken();
        context.write(new Text(eachWord), one);
    }


    }
}
```

I have written my Own Combiner

Here is my Combiner Code :

```
public class WordCountCombiner extends Reducer<Text ,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {


protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException
{
    int count =0;
    for(IntWritable i : values)
    {
        count =count+i.get();
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
}

}
```

My Question here is What output will it get stored .

The Output of Mapper or output of combiner?

Or Combiner will get executed only if there is reducer phase written?

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure how many times the combiner function will run or if at all it will run. Also running the combiner is not dependent on if you specify reducer for your job. In your case it will simply produce 160 output files (10240/64=160)

Comment: I am getting the mapper output alone .  In Mapper code the just created map key and constant  new IntWritable(1) as mapoutputvalue .in combiner code i have included logic for addition .

Comment: I am getting the mapper output alone . Hi 1 How 1 Are 1 something like this .also look at console logs  Job job_201502260931_72501 completed successfully
Launched map tasks=500
Data-local map tasks=500
Aggregate execution time of reducers(ms)=0
FileSystemCounters
MAPRFS_BYTES_READ=4213018503
MAPRFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=5025563869
FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=25879174
Map-Reduce Framework
Map input records=28997989
PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=282704257024
CPU_MILLISECONDS=753350
VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=1571293040640
Map output records=405971846
SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=66500
GC time elapsed (ms)=1402

Comment: Yes since you have specified job.setNumReduceTasks(0)  so there will not be any reducer in this scenario. And even if you specified your reducer logic  for the combiner we cant say if combiner will run or not if at all. So it is possible that your combiner will not run at all. if you want to know how it is decided if combiner will run read more about disc spill  in hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

By skipping the setting of mapper and reducer, the hadoop will move forward with its default mapping.
For example, it will use

1. IdentityMapper.class as a default mapper.
2. The default input format is TextInputFormat.
3. The default partitioner is HashPartitione.
4. By default, there is a single reducer, and therefore a single partition.
5. The default reducer is Reducer, again a generic type.
6. The default output format is TextOutputFormat, which writes out records, one per line, by converting keys and values to strings and separating them with a tab character